# How to prevent appium from re-installing apk each time when i run tests on windows machine

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I'm new to Appium Mobile Automation tool.

**Server version:** 1.4.16.1

**OS**: Windows 7

**What I'm Doing:** 
Actually the way Appium is installing apk on my **Android device** its changing the behavior of App. Eg: AutoCompletetextview not showing suggestions when apk is installed via Appium otherwise it behaves perfectly when app is installed manually.

When i searched "How to override Appium's Apk installation functionality?"

I found these in [Appium Documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.0.0/?java#running-appium)  before asking the question here

- you must supply the –no-reset and –full-reset flags currently for
  android  to work on Windows.
- There exists a hardware accelerated    emulator for android, it has
  it’s own limitations.
- For more    information you can check out this    page.Make sure that
  hw.battery=yes in your AVD’s config.ini

But still couldn't apply this knowledge on Windows Machine. Any help is appreciated.

.

Answer (score 7):

There are one or more things we can do to stop installing the App again and again.

**a. Setting appium --no-reset Flag to true :** This Flag is used when we don't want to reset app state between sessions (Android: don’t uninstall app before new session). Its default Value is False,

We can start your Appium server with "appium --no-reset" command or include server capability like:

> capabilities.setCapability("noReset","true");

**b. Make Sure --full-reset Flag is False:** (Android) Reset app state by uninstalling app instead of clearing app data. On Android, this will also remove the app after the session is complete. Default false.

> capabilities.setCapability("fullReset","false");

Comment: works on nodejs webdriverio

Answer (score 3):

You have to uncheck **Full Reset** in Appium Configurations.
And restart Appium then launch it.

Answer (score 3):

Use package name and activity name instead of apk path , pre condition is app needs to be installed first , 
It'll not reset or reinstall app and just launches the app

Comment: Okay, so the appium wont find the apk file to install rather use the package and activity name to launch the application already installed?

Comment: I have been trying to get a solution for this thing. Let me try this.!

Comment: Also you can use no-reset flag and set to to true

Comment: It didn't work for my requirements, I am doing a force-stop with adb and then launching it with Start_App activity

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Launch Appium --> Go To Android Settings--> Uncheck Full Reset

Answer (score 0):

If you select Full Reset then each time appium will reinstall your apk. Uncheck Full Reset and try

Comment: And how to Uncheck this Full reset option?  Could you please walk  me through the steps on a Windows Machine @Raj?

Comment: Launch Appium --> Go To Android Settings--> Uncheck Full Reset